# Sagemaker saving inference to s3

Tags: boto3, amazon-sagemaker, inference, machine-learning-model

I've been trying to find an example on how to upload image file to s3 from inference.py script.  I used my regular boto3 but it's giving me error.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket='s3:{bucket}'
object_name= file_name
s3_url = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```

It's complaining that it can't find boto3.  Is it not allowed to import boto3 from inference.py?

```
invokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message \"No module named 'boto3'\n
```

Comment: where this script is running ? is that a notebook or a custom container or pre-built container?

Comment: @rok the script is passed during PyTorchModel creation as the "entry_point" parameter.

Comment: How does your requirements.txt file look like?